# Relative filepaths and SVG symbols

Tags: svg, xlink

It took me a lot of time to figure out an error while playing around with SVG symbols and I still have the question "why?".

I tried to include and SVG symbol using `xlink:href` like this:

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="../node_modules/icons/icons.svg#my_icon_24px"></use>
</svg>
```

but the icon did not render at all. Althought the file was linked correctly. (I could open it when I clicked on the link to the SVG file in the source code.)

But when I copy the file `icons.svg` into the same dir my html file is in and then include it like this:

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="icons.svg#my_icon_24px"></use>
</svg>
```

it works perfect. Are there any known issues with relative filepaths regarding `xlink:href`? I guess the `..` was the problem.

The SVG didn't render in Firefox neither in Chrome. But why?

**UPDATE**

Okay seems to be a problem of opening a local HTML file without a webserver. I opened the HTML file in the browser with `file://`. When I open it over a webserver both paths work perfect.

At least Google Chrome gives a hint:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL file:///....../node_modules/icons/icons.svg#my-icon from frame with URL file:///....../web/index.html. **'file:' URLs are treated as unique security origins.**

Comment: Firefox, only subdirectories allowed. Chrome only same directory allowed. Why? You can surely see how xlink:href="/etc/password" might lead to issues can't you?